# Building Docker images on Windows: Entrypoint script "no such file or directory"

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I wasted two days on this until I finally figured out my problem, so I thought I'd share. I'll outline the problem I was having here, and then outline the solutions in the answer.

My `Dockerfile` looked something like this,

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

COPY custom-docker-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["custom-docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

I had a file `custom-docker-php-entrypont` in the same directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

However, when I ran `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker-compose logs -f` my php container show as failing with `exit code 1` saying `exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

[image: test-php | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" test-php exited with code 1]

I then loaded up the container with a different entrypoint command and used bash to look inside and confirm that the file was being copied into the location that I expected it to be.

I thought, "Maybe this is a permissions thing?" so I tried setting `chmod 777 custom-docker-php-entrypoint`, but that also didn't solve my problem. I also tried setting it to executable with `chmod -x custom-docker-php-entrypoint`, but that also didn't help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So, even though logs say "no such file or directory," the actual problem (at least in my case) was due to the difference in end-of-line (EOL) characters on Windows and Linux. Windows uses `CRLF` represent the end of a line and Unix/Linux uses `LF`.

I hadn't consider this as a potential problem since the files were freshly cloned from Github and were originally created on Linux. What I didn't know is that on Windows Git is set up to automatically convert EOL characters to `CRLF`.

## Making Git retain original EOL characters (disabling `autocrlf`).

There are a few ways to go about doing this. `autocrlf` is the name of the attribute that decides whether git converts line endings. You'd only need to do one of the following options depending on what you need.

#### Disable `autocrlf` for one command

You can clone the files with the following to disable `autocrlf` as just a one time thing.

```
git clone https://github.com/someuser/somerepo --config core.autocrlf=false
```

#### Specify EOL type in `.gitattributes`

If you have a single repo that you know you want to always have autocrlf disabled, you can specify it in that repo's `.gitattributes` file. Just add the following line to your `.gitattributes` file.

```
* text eol=lf
```

#### Disable `autocrlf` in Git's config file

Navigate to the folder where Git is installed on your machine. For me it was installed at `C:\ProgramData\Git`. Open `config` in a text editor. Change `autocrlf=true` to `autocrlf=false`.

[image]

## Changing EOL characters on existing files.

If you've got existing entrypoint scripts that you need to convert, or if you're writing your entrypoint scripts in Windows in the first place, you can easily set the EOL type with most popular text editors. I'll outline how to do it in Vim, Notepad++, and Sublime, but it should be easy enough to figure out by searching "change EOL" and the name of your text editor of choice.

#### Using Vim

To change the line endings to be compatible with Linux, do `:set ff=unix`. To change them so that they are compatible with Windows, do `:set ff=dos`.

#### Using Notepad++

On the menu bar click on `Edit` and then go to `EOL Conversion` and select the desired conversion. You'll want to select `Unix (LF)` to make it compatible with Linux.

#### Using Sublime

On the menu bar click 'View' and go to 'Line Endings' and from there select the desired conversion. You'll want to select `Unix` to make it compatible with Linux.

## Converting EOL characters from your Dockerfile.

Alternatively, there's a useful tool called `dos2unix` that you can install in your image and use to convert your entrypoint script. Assuming an **Ubuntu** or **Debian** based image which uses **apt-get** , you can use it in the following way.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dos2unix

COPY custom-docker-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/

RUN dos2unix /usr/local/bin/custom-docker-php-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["custom-docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

If your Docker image is based on **Alpine** linux using **apk** for a package manager, you'll want to do something like this,

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --update add bash && \
    apk add dos2unix

COPY entrypoint.sh /

RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

If your Docker image is based on **Centos** using **yum** as a package manager, you'll want to do something like this,

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install dos2unix -y

COPY entrypoint.sh /

RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 x64...I ran dos2unix.exe recursively on EVERY file within my project. I added the `apt-get install dos2unix` and `RUN dos2unix` in my Dockerfile. Nothing works. I want to die. These line ending solutions all over the internet aren't working for me

Comment: Maybe entertain the possibility that the file actually isn't found? Like maybe one of the paths have a typo in it? Or maybe it is a permissions error that's causing the file to seem as though it can't be found?

Comment: Just today I found an easy way to keep git from converting shell files to windows EOL - it seems by adding a .gitattributes to the top level of your project, you can tell git what eol to default to for specific file types, like shell scripts - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674232/8127899