# Docker COPY - Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I try to create image from docker. Everything works fine for linux and macos, but now for windows 10.
I have this line in Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

and after create image on windows and try to run, get this error:

```
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

Why?

Please explain what the different?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the line ending character.

You might need to update the line ending form `CRLF -> LF`.

There are a lot of ways to do this, easist with `Notepad++`

open the file with Notepad++ and aim to `edit` --> `EOL conversion` and choose `LF`.

Save the `dockerfile` and try again.

More about changing line ending char can be found in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810758/how-to-replace-crlf-with-lf-in-a-single-file)

Comment: If this is in fact the issue, also see [Building Docker images on Windows: Entrypoint script "no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165471/building-docker-images-on-windows-entrypoint-script-no-such-file-or-directory) which gives several more suggestions.